# How to share the global variables between two modules by using Perl CLI Framework?

Tags: perl, frameworks, command-line-interface

I am using Perl CLI Framework to write some script. Now I want to pass the variable from the control module to the sub-command module. I have tried to set the variable as the global variable in the control module but the sub-command module still cannot get the variable. It is even not able to share the global variable in the same module. There are some error messages when executing the script:

[root@old]# perl pc --ip=dsfa --device dsfasdf on
Use of uninitialized value $Power::Control::data in concatenation (.) or string at Power/Control.pm line 63.

The globla data is 
Use of uninitialized value $Power::Control::data in concatenation (.) or string at Power/Control.pm line 75.

The data from parent is

The device name is dsfasdf

The ip address is dsfa

This is the command on

Here is the script pc:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Power::Control;

use lib 'lib';

# ---- EXECUTION ----
Power::Control->run(); # Launch command
```

Here is the Power/Control.pm:

```
package Power::Control;
use base qw( CLI::Framework );

use strict;
use warnings;

sub usage_text {
    qq{
    $0 [--verbose|v]:

    OPTIONS:
        --verbose -v:   be vebose

    ARGUMENTS (subcommands):
        on:         power on the device
        off:        power off the device
        reboot:     reboot the device
        version:    show PDU version
        status:     show PDU status
        sysstat:    show PDU sysstatus
    }
}

sub option_spec {
    [ 'device|d=s'     => 'device name' ],
    [ 'ip=s'           => 'ip address' ],
    [ 'user|u=s'       => 'user name' ],
    [ 'password|p=s'   => 'password' ],
    [ 'interval|i=s'   => 'interval' ],
    [ 'brand|b=s'      => 'brand' ],
    [ 'community|c=s'  => 'community' ],
    [ 'version|v=s'    => 'version' ],
}

sub command_map {
    on      => 'Power::Control::Command::On',
    off     => 'Power::Control::Command::Off',
    reboot  => 'Power::Control::Command::Reboot',
    version => 'Power::Control::Command::Version',
    status  => 'Power::Control::Command::Status',
    sysstat => 'Power::Control::Command::Sysstat',
}

sub command_alias {
    r   => 'reboot',
    v   => 'version',
    st  => 'status',
    sys => 'sysstat',
}

our $opts;
our $self;
our $data;

sub init {
    ($self, $opts) = @_;

    $data = $opts->{'ip'};
    print "\n The device name is $opts->{'device'}\n";
    print "\n The ip address is $data\n";
}

print "\n The globla data is $data\n";
1;

# ---- COMMAND: On ----
package Power::Control::Command::On;
use base qw( CLI::Framework::Command );

use strict;
use warnings;
use Power::Control;
use Data::Dumper;

print "\n The data from parent is $data \n";

sub usage_text {
    q{
    on [--d=<device name>: Power on the device
    }
}

#sub option_spec {
#    [ 'device|d=s@'   => 'device name'  ],
#}

sub run {

    print "\n This is the command on\n";
}
1;
```

Comment: Why not separate files- one module/function per file?  Then your controller module can just make system() calls.

Comment: It sounds like you are accessing something in the wrong scope somewhere but who knows for sure? The code you have posted is mixed up and some of the content seems to have been double pasted or pasted over missing lines. Can you clean up the code and then show us what is in the script "```pc```"?  This is the only way you'll get useful responses.

Comment: I have updated my post. Added the script pc.

Comment: was the answer below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for following up on this. I took a minute or two to organize and separate the files into a typical `lib/Power/Control.pm` and `lib/Power/Control/Command/On.pm`  layout and cleaned up a few things and here's the output I got:

```
[localhost ~/tmp%]  perl stackex-pc --ip=127.0.0.1 --device=pants on
The device name is pants
The ip address is 127.0.0.1
This is the command "on"
```

Which I think is more or less what you want. I'll add my explanation of what I think was going on below but first I'll include my files and you can try this at home.  If it works then you can accept my answer.  If I give a decent explanation then others can vote me up!!  First, here's the script:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/perl
#
# stackex-pc 
# Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054798

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib 'lib' ;
use Power::Control;

# ---- EXECUTION ----
Power::Control->run(); # Launch command
```

And here's the packages:

```
# lib/Power/Control.pm
# Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054798

package Power::Control;   
use base qw( CLI::Framework );
use strict;
use warnings;

our ($data, $opts, $self);

sub usage_text {
   qq{
   $0 [--verbose|v]:

OPTIONS:
    --verbose -v:   be vebose

ARGUMENTS (subcommands):
    on:         power on the device
    off:        power off the device
    reboot:     reboot the device
    version:    show PDU version
    status:     show PDU status
    sysstat:    show PDU sysstatus
    }
}

sub option_spec {
    [ 'device|d=s'     => 'device name' ],
    [ 'ip=s'           => 'ip address' ],
    [ 'user|u=s'       => 'user name' ],
    [ 'password|p=s'   => 'password' ],
    [ 'interval|i=s'   => 'interval' ],
    [ 'brand|b=s'      => 'brand' ],
    [ 'community|c=s'  => 'community' ],
    [ 'version|v=s'    => 'version' ],
}

sub command_map {
    on      => 'Power::Control::Command::On',
    off     => 'Power::Control::Command::Off',
    reboot  => 'Power::Control::Command::Reboot',
    version => 'Power::Control::Command::Version',
    status  => 'Power::Control::Command::Status',
    sysstat => 'Power::Control::Command::Sysstat',
}

sub command_alias {
    r   => 'reboot',
    v   => 'version',
    st  => 'status',
    sys => 'sysstat',
}

sub init {
    ($self, $opts) = @_;

    print "\n The device name is $opts->{device}\n";
    print "\n The ip address is $opts->{ip}\n";
}

1;
```

As mentioned I separated the files in a module directory type layout so there's a second file. I did this for my own convenience, so don't feel you have to do the same thing.

```
# lib/Power/Control/Command/On.pm                                                                                   
# Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054798

package Power::Control::Command::On;        
use base qw( CLI::Framework::Command );     
use strict;                                                                      
use warnings;                                                                    
use Power::Control;                                                              
                                                                            
sub usage_text {                                                                 
    q{                                                                           
    on [--d=<device name>: Power on the device
    }                                                                            
}                                                                            
                                                                            
sub run {                                                                    
    print "\n This is the command \"on\" \n";
    exit ;
}   
1;
```

I think the reason your first approach didn't work was - just as the error message indicated - uninitialized variables. My attempted explanation follows:

1. I needed to place `use lib 'lib';` *before*  `use Power::Control;` otherwise the script would not have a complete @INC and was unable to find `Power::Control`.  When I fixed this I got the same error as you. This suggests that you may have set up your CLI::Framework differently or had put your own modules somewhere in the @INC.
2. If you change `"our $data ;`  on line 53 of `lib/Power/Control.pm`  `our $data = "in the global scope";`  - which is otherwise undefined - you'll see that message when you run the script. The "$data" value is not getting set from inside the init() subroutine  If you replace `print "\n The ip address is $data\n";` in the init() subroutine around line 60 in `lib/Power/Control.pm` with `print "\n The ip address is $opts->{ip}\n";` you'll get output more like you expect.  You'll also get a sense for the effect of different lexical values for variable if you change `$data =`  inside `init()` to read `my $otherdata = ...` and adjust the `print` line accordingly.
3. I'm not done yet!  I'll review/edit my explanation and add a few references about variable scope and just what the `$data` variable is doing inside this `CLI::Framework` app.

BTW, it's tricky, but you can figure out a lot of this by running the script in the perl debugger by simply adding the `-d` switch to your command:

`perl -d pc --ip=dsfa --device dsfasdf on`.

and then stepping through the script as it runs, trying to dump variable values, tracing, etc.

If you try puttiing the `on` command argument *before* the `--ip=` options you'll see another kind of problem: the command line argument parsing is a bit fragile.  There is likely an elegant check you could add to fix that too or at least make the `Failed parsing of command options` a bit more meaningful (e.g. send the usage screen to the user).

Good luck with your project.